# Class is being removed with lazy loading JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, lazy-loading

I am trying to Lazy load some images onto a website. The problem that I am encountering is that I have to remove the class for the lazy loading to work but I still want the CSS properties to be used by the image. Can anyone help?

```js
// JavaScript Document
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var lazyImages = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("img.Images"));

  if ("IntersectionObserver" in window) {
    let lazyImageObserver = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries, observer) {
      entries.forEach(function(entry) {
        if (entry.isIntersecting) {
          let lazyImage = entry.target;
          lazyImage.src = lazyImage.dataset.src;
          lazyImage.srcset = lazyImage.dataset.srcset;
          lazyImage.classList.remove("Images");
          lazyImageObserver.unobserve(lazyImage);
        }
      });
    });

    lazyImages.forEach(function(lazyImage) {
      lazyImageObserver.observe(lazyImage);
    });
  } else {
    // Possibly fall back to a more compatible method here
  }
});
```

```css
.Images {
  width: 190px;
  height: 190px;
  padding: 10px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<img class="Images" src="https://i.imgur.com/mf5YDAy.jpg" data-src="https://i.imgur.com/mf5YDAy.jpg" data-srcset="https://i.imgur.com/mf5YDAy.jpg, https://i.imgur.com/mf5YDAy.jpg" />
```

Comment: Use two different classes, one for style and one for the lazy loading.

Comment: Why do you have to remove the class for the lazy loading to work?? I don't get it..